# Emails by joomlahost warn me I should update Joomla version on unknown domain

Tags: security, error-handling, versions, emails

I have a small personal website, say

```
namesurname.joomlafree.it
```

made with Joomla 2.5 (remote installation, that I keep updated regularly, actually to 2.5.19).

It is the third time already in the latest 2-3 months that I recieve the same email from `no-reply@joomlahost.it`. Written in italian, this email basically says that there is an old version of Joomla (2.5.18) on the domain

```
tmp.namesurname.joomlafree.it
```

I do not know which domain is this, starting with **tmp.**, nor how to have access to its administration.

I had already posted [such question](http://forum.joomla.it/index.php/topic,239986.msg1112768.html#msg1112768) on joomla forum in italian language: I was only answered that it was possibly an error, but this happens again.

Do you ever hear about this kind of domain? Any possible explanation or idea about how to deal with it? May not taking care of such emails lead to a lack in security?

I only know and manage to use the url *without* **tmp.** in the beginning and I would like to keep *it* up to date. Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered contacting them directly? This does not really seem a Joomla issue.

Comment: Try upgradingto 2.5.20 and see if they will send you an email

Comment: If you get a response from joomlafree.it (who I hope you are contacting!), be sure to post back the resolution that you get from them as an answer in case anyone else stumbles on this question!

Comment: @David Fritsch: Done! Let us see what they say. Give you an update in (hope) 48 hours...

Comment: @David Fritsch: They answered. A brief email signed by Colt Engine support team explains me that, in order not to recieve such notification anymore, I am advised to delete the whole folder named **tmp** from **public_html** folder. I do not know what this tmp (*temporary*?) folder is for, I will now look into that and consider removing. Hope this may be useful even if the question is on hold.

Comment: @David Fritsch: I have deleted the **tmp** folder (see my comment just above) and this did not affect any of the site applications. I will post updated comments if I keep recieving such emails in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try contacting your host, they will know for sure.
It may be in a subdirectory of your site or somewhere completely different. Depending on their setup it doesn't even have to belong to you.

Without a real URL where we could have a look, it's almost impossible to say anything at all.

Comment: I would add: do a lookup and see if the IP address of the site is one that you recognize.

Comment: @Bakual: *real* urls are matteoallegro.joomlafree.it ... and tmp.matteoallegro.joomlafree.it, thank you.

Comment: Hmm, that tmp adress doesn't even resolve.
I would forward the email to joomlahost.it and ask them to solve the issue. Looks like something is wrong in their database/script.